# sharedpreferences putting an array

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

how can I use this code in order to add an array and retrieve it later?
can I use a simple for loop?

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("isChk", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("keys",ArrayValue[i] );
  editor.commit();
```

and how can I then retrieve them and store each element in an array variable can I use this?

```
for( int i=0; i<myArr.size(); i++){
keys[i] = settings.getBoolean("isChk", false);
isChkb.add(keys[i]);
}
```

Comment: You want to create arraylist from array ??

Comment: You can only store boolean, int, float, long and Strings. The only way to store an array is to use the String option and add all your variables together and then decode it as an array when you need it again (see answers below).

Comment: noooo just save the array to the storage and then read it back when needed

Comment: yes i got that thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store an `array` in `sharedPreferences` , you can put your `array values` in a `String` , then *store* this `String` .. and if you you want to get your `array value` (in our case ,stored in a string) , you *get* the `string` and `parse` it using `StringTokenizer` like this :  **(In my example I will store and retreive an array of Boolean)**

- Put your booleans into a string, delimiting every int by a character, for example a comma, and then save them as a string:

  ```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  Boolean[] list = new Boolean[10];
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  str.append(list[i]).append(",");
  }
  prefs.edit().putBoolean("keys", str.toString()).commit();
  ```
- Get the string and parse it using StringTokenizer:

  ```
  String savedString = prefs.getString("string", "");
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
  Boolean[] savedList = new Boolean[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      savedList[i] = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken();
    }
  ```

Comment: you'r welcome , i use this way because it's simple and do what i want perfectly

Comment: i am having trouble understanding what happens at the first launch of the application where the preferences are not yet present doesn't it return an error ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how u do to save Array in Shared Preferences

```
public static boolean saveTheArray()
{
 SharedPreferences sharedpref = SharedPreferences.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sharedpref .edit();
 mEdit1.putInt("Status_size", array.size()); //array-> the array to be saved 

for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)  
{
    mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);
    mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i, array.get(i));  
}

return mEdit1.commit();
```

}

To retriev it use the following code:

```
public static void loadArray(Context mContext)
{  
SharedPreferences mShrdPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
array.clear();
int size = mShrdPref.getInt("Status_size", 0);  

for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
{
    array.add(mShrdPref.getString("Status_" + i, null));
}
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: and in order to get retrieve the array can i use the same function and replace the put by get ?

Comment: is this still applicable  isChkb.add(settings.getBoolean("Status_" + i, false)); 
after using the puBoolean() so i store boolean values

Answer (score 0):

Use key names instead of `isChk` to get value of keys from `SharedPreferences` because  `isChk` is SharedPreferences name :

```
keys[i] = settings.getBoolean("keys", false);
```

Also you are saving all values with same key `keys` so you only get last value which you have added. to store all values use unique keys like `"keys"+i`.

For more how we add Array in SharedPreferences see this post:

[Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)